# How do I print the highest/longest values in a file

Tags: bash, sorting, awk, sed, grep

I have an AV log file showing a number of values for each process scanned: Name, Path, Total files scanned, Scan time. The file contains hundreds of these process entries (example below) and for *Total files scanned*  and *Scan time* I'd like to sort and print the highest (or longest) values so I can determine which processes are impacting the system. I've tried various ways with grep but only seem to get a list running in numerical order, when what I really want is to say Process id: 86, Scan time (ns): 12761174 is the highest, then Process id 25, etc. Hope my explanation is clear enough.

```
Process id: 25
Name: wwww
Path: "/usr/libexec/wwww"
Total files scanned: 42
Scan time (ns): "62416"
Status: Active

Process id: 7
Name: xxxx
Path: "/usr/libexec/xxxx"
Total files scanned: 0
Scan time (ns): "0"
Status: Active

Process id: 86
Name: yyyy
Path: "/usr/libexec/yyyy"
Total files scanned: 2
Scan time (ns): "12761174"
Status: Active
```

I have tried:

```
grep -Eo | grep 'Scan time (ns)' '[0-9]+' file | sort
```

Which results in:

```
file:Scan time (ns): "9391986"
file:Scan time (ns): "9532119"
file:Scan time (ns): "9730650"
file:Scan time (ns): "9743828"
file:Scan time (ns): "9793469"
file:Scan time (ns): "9911768"
```

What I am wanting to achieve is something such as:

```
Process id 9, Scan time (ns): "34561"
Process id 86, Scan time (ns): "45630"
Process id 25, Scan time (ns): "1256822"
Process id 51, Scan time (ns): "52351290"
Process id 30, Scan time (ns): "90257651"
Process id 19, Scan time (ns): "178764794932"
```

Comment: please update the question to show the (wrong) output generated by your code and the ( correct) expected output, making sure both sets of output correspond with the provided sample input

Comment: what's the point of the first grep?

Comment: Meant to remove that, it's superfluous

Comment: From where do you get 34561? Please add your desired output for exact that sample input to your question.

Comment: obviously `grep 'Scan time (ns)' '[0-9]+' file` doesn't work because `grep` receives only 1 pattern by default, the rest non-option parameters are input files. If you want `grep` to find multiple patterns then you need to use `-e`: `grep -e 'Scan time (ns)' -e '[0-9]+' file`, or use a regex pattern: `grep -P 'Scan time \(ns\)|[0-9]+' file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another approach. It uses `sed` and `sort`:

```
sed '/^Process id:/h; /^Scan time (ns):/!d; s/"//g; H; x; s/\n/, /' file | sort -k7,7n
```

Note: I've removed double quotes around the scan time values (double quotes around integer values make little sense to me).

Comment: This works beautifully and is more or less what I was looking for, so thank you

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```bash
awk '
/^Process id: /{
  val=$NF
  next
}
/^Scan time \(ns\): "/{
  arr[val]=$NF
}
END{
  PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"
  for(i in arr){
    print "Process id " i ", Scan time (ns): " arr[i]""
}
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: This outputs cleanly but doesn't give me the order I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

Using `perl` to read the records one at a time (Using "paragraph mode" which uses a blank line as a record seperator), extract the time, and sort in reverse order by it:

```bash
$ perl -00 -lne 'm/Scan time \(ns\):\s+"(\d+)"/ && push @procs, [ $_, $1 ];
                 END { print $_->[0] for sort { $a->[1] < $b->[1] } @procs }' input.txt
Process id: 86
Name: yyyy
Path: "/usr/libexec/yyyy"
Total files scanned: 2
Scan time (ns): "12761174"
Status: Active

Process id: 25
Name: wwww
Path: "/usr/libexec/wwww"
Total files scanned: 42
Scan time (ns): "62416"
Status: Active

Process id: 7
Name: xxxx
Path: "/usr/libexec/xxxx"
Total files scanned: 0
Scan time (ns): "0"
Status: Active
```

Comment: This executes cleanly but only cats the file, I see no reordering

Comment: @onthenile Look closer

Comment: I see the logic in your example, with the reverse order working, but in my local copy of the file, which has hundreds of process ids, those ids still run numerically and so I  don't see a list an ordered list of low `Scan time (ns)` values to high ones (or in reverse)

Answer (score 1):

A combination of awk's `RS` (input record separator) and `FS` (input field separator) are useful in this case:

```
< inpt awk 'BEGIN { RS = ""; FS = "\n" } { print $1 ", " $5 }' | sort -t \" -k2n
```

- Before starting to process anything, i.e in the `BEGIN`, we set

  - `RS` to `""`, meaning that records are separated by empty lines, and
  - `FS` to `"\n"`, meaning that (in each record) the fields are separated by a line break;
- then we proceed by printing the 1st and 5th field, with a comma in between.
- Finally, interpreting each line of the stream as `"`-separated list of fields, we `sort` `n`umerically according to the second field (`-k2`).

Comment: My result is `=====================================, Total files scanned: 0`. Is "inpt" the file name? I assumed so.

Comment: @onthenile, yes, `inpt` is the file name. What happens if you remove `| sort ...`? What system are you on?

Comment: No change in result when removing that pipe and onwards. System is macOS but using RHEL is the same output.

Comment: @onthenile, what do `echo -e '1\n2\n\n3\n4\n' | awk 'BEGIN { RS = ""; ORS = "x" } 1 { print $1 }'` and `echo -e '1,2' | awk 'BEGIN { FS = ","; OFS = ";" } { print $1, $2 }'` print?

Answer (score 1):

With just `paste`:

```
$ cat file | paste - - - - - - -
Process id: 25  Name: wwww  Path: "/usr/libexec/wwww"   Total files scanned: 42 Scan time (ns): "62416" Status: Active  
Process id: 7   Name: xxxx  Path: "/usr/libexec/xxxx"   Total files scanned: 0  Scan time (ns): "0" Status: Active  
Process id: 86  Name: yyyy  Path: "/usr/libexec/yyyy"   Total files scanned: 2  Scan time (ns): "12761174"  Status: Active
```

And if we add some formatting:

```
$ cat file \
    | paste - - - - - - - \
    | awk '{
        printf("process id: %s, scan time (ns): %s\n", $3, $15);
    }'
process id: 25, scan time (ns): "62416"
process id: 7, scan time (ns): "0"
process id: 86, scan time (ns): "12761174"
```

Those are 7 dashes (`-`), because each one of your records is 7 lines (including the blank line).

Explanation of the hack:

`paste` will concatenate the 1st line of all input files into a single line, then concatenate the 2nd line and so on.
So for each input file, in order, it reads a line and adds it to it's current output line.
We've given stdin as input, 7 times. But stdin is a single stream.

So `paste` will do:

- read line 1 from input 1 (line 1 of stdin)
- read line 1 from input 2 (line 2 of stdin)
- ...
- read line 1 from input 7 (line 7 of stdin)
- concatenate these lines (lines 1-7 of stdin) as line 1 of stdout
- read line 2 from input 1 (line 8 of stdin)
- ...
- read line 2 from input 7 (line 14 of stdin)
- concatenate these lines (lines 8-14 of stdin) as line 2 of stdout
- ...